# Will Partitioning a Solid State Drive make it faster?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, storage

I know that partitioning a conventional HDD drive will make it faster. Is the same true for Solid state drives? Does partitioning a solid state drive make it faster?

Comment: Why do you think partitioning a drive will make it "faster"? I think your premise is incorrect. On spinning drives it can potentially make head seeks quicker since it has less distance to travel, but that is so minute in modern it is hardly noticeable except in benchmarks, but there is no head to move in an SSD drive. This was sometimes noticeable in older drives where storage was measured in megabytes, but modern drives it is rarely noticeable unless you are splitting it up into many parts.

Comment: @acejavelin - actually short stroking a drive can provide sustantial improvements in real performance - a 30% increase in sequential read speed is quite conservative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few logic errors here.

On an SSD drive, partitioning the drive will not make it faster, as it takes an equal amount of time to read any part of it - the data does not need to spin under the head.  Further, it will move underlying blocks around, so a partition will not actually represent a contiguous block of cells.

On a hard drive, partitioning the drive won't make it faster per se - what it will do is allow you to modify the performance characteristics of the drive by limiting where tracks can be written to disk - Writing to the outer edge of the drive is about twice as fast as reading the innermost tracks.  This is called "[short stroking](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2014/07/how-to-short-stroke-your-hard-drive-for-optimal-speed/)" a drive.